# large ui select box

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

im using semantic-ui, but in my search form when i implement the large input fields, the select option field doesnt takes effect, is still with the same size, am i implementing the right way? Looking the documentation it looks that im doing it right i guess.

html

```
 <div class="ui large form">


                <div class="four fields">
                  <div class="field">
                   <select class="large ui dropdown">
                    <option value="">All areas</option>
                    <option value="1">Chef</option>
                    <option value="0">Barman</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>

                   <div class="field">

                    <select class="large ui dropdown">
                      <option value="">All resgions</option>
                      <option value="1">New york</option>
                      <option value="0">London</option>
                    </select>

                  </div>


                  <div class="field">

                    <input placeholder="Ex: Position, etc" type="text">
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">

                    <div class="large ui blue button"><i class="search icon"></i> Search</div>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the dropdown docs that would suggest you can use sizing: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: This really sucks, doesnt make sense, inf there for a input why shouldnt have for selec options...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style for large dropdown in the select:

```
min-height: 2.7142em;
```

or try to use their custom dropdown with html/js:

```
<div class="ui selection large dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Gender</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```